# loop through all tables and delete records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm new to MsSql and I'm not sure if this can be done but I figured I'd ask before I want on my way with the current process..

I need to create a script that loops through all tables in a database and deletes the rows where CorporationId = "xxx". There are a few tables that do not have this column, but of my ~50 tables, only 1 or two do not.

I can individually delete the records in the table with this:

```
USE MyDatabase

DECLARE @CorporationId UniqueIdentifier
DECLARE @TokenId UniqueIdentifier
DECLARE @CompanyCode nChar(3)

SET @CorporationId = '52D3AEFE-8EBD-4669-8096-4596FE83BB36'

print 'Starting Web.GasOrder'

DELETE FROM Web.GasOrder
WHERE       CorporationId = @CorporationId

print 'Starting Web.GasOrderNumber'

DELETE FROM Web.GasOrderNumber
WHERE       CorporationId = @CorporationId

etc..
```

But this is getting tedious creating one for each table.

Of course, **some of the tables have relationships on them.**

Is there an easy way to do this or do I need to do it manually for each table?

**UPDATE**

Most of the options that I have tried run into problems with relationships and give me an error.

Comment: Yes, you can do this with dynamic SQL. I'll write it up, but someone else will probably beat me to it. :)

Comment: enforce cascade delete?

Comment: We don't have that on our tables and can't add it at this point. Thx though.

Comment: Going to ask what is prob a dumb question, but do any of these options take into account relationships? If a table has a relationship on it and a delete it attempted on it, won't it cause a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another one... could easily be changed to a stored procedure...

```
Declare @corpID Nvarchar(256)
Set     @corpID = 'xxx'

If      Object_ID('tempdb..#tables') Is Not Null Drop Table #tables
Create  Table #tables (tID Int, SchemaName Nvarchar(256), TableName Nvarchar(256))

Insert  #tables
Select  Row_Number() Over (Order By s.name, so.name), s.name, so.name
From    sysobjects so
Join    sys.schemas s
        On  so.uid = s.schema_id
Join    syscolumns sc
        On  so.id = sc.id
Where   so.xtype = 'u'
And     sc.name = 'CorporationId'

Declare @SQL Nvarchar(Max),
        @schema Nvarchar(256),
        @table Nvarchar(256),
        @iter Int = 1

While   Exists (Select  1
                From    #tables)
Begin

        Select  @schema = SchemaName,
                @table = TableName
        From    #tables
        Where   tID = @iter

        If      Exists (Select  1
                        From    sysobjects o
                        Join    sys.schemas s1
                                On  o.uid = s1.schema_id
                        Join    sysforeignkeys fk
                                On  o.id = fk.rkeyid
                        Join    sysobjects o2
                                On  fk.fkeyid = o2.id
                        Join    sys.schemas s2
                                On  o2.uid = s2.schema_id
                        Join    #tables t
                                On  o2.name = t.TableName Collate Database_Default
                                And s2.name = t.SchemaName Collate Database_Default
                        Where   o.name = @table
                        And     s1.name = @schema)
        Begin
                Update  t
                Set     tID = (Select Max(tID) From #tables) + 1
                From    #tables t
                Where   tableName = @table
                And     schemaName = @schema

                Set     @iter = @iter + 1
        End
        Else
        Begin
                Set     @Sql = 'Delete t
                                From    [' + @schema + '].[' + @table + '] t
                                Where   CorporationId = ''' + @corpID + ''''

                Exec    sp_executeSQL @SQL;

                Delete  t
                From    #tables t
                Where   tableName = @table
                And     schemaName = @schema

                Set     @iter = @iter + 1

        End
End
```

Comment: tested this one and got a few of these:  (0 row(s) affected)
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_CorporationStructure_Level". The conflict occurred in database "SuburbanTest", table "Company.CorporationStructure", column 'LevelId'. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Ooooooh, now it gets interesting, we have to take foreign keys into consideration to get the proper ordering for the deletes. This is an issue that I think you'll have with all the proposed solutions at the moment. I'll see if I can modify mine to delete them in the proper order.

Answer (score 6):

[`sp_MSForEachTable`](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2007/10/23/60383.aspx) is an undocumented stored procedure which will run a command for each table in the database:

```
USE MyDatabase

DECLARE @CorporationId VARCHAR(50)
SET @CorporationId = '52D3AEFE-8EBD-4669-8096-4596FE83BB36'

DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Sql = '
IF COL_LENGTH(''?'',''CorporationId'') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Web.?
    WHERE CorporationId = ''' + @CorporationId + '''
END
'

EXEC sp_MSForEachTable @Sql
```

Comment: I got two messages with this: **1.**  Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 4
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_CorporationStructure_Level". The conflict occurred in database "SuburbanTest", table "Company.CorporationStructure", column 'LevelId'.
The statement has been terminated. **2.** Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 Invalid column name 'CorporationId'.

Answer (score 2):

You could run a query like this:

```
SELECT 'DELETE FROM [' + s.name + '].[' + t.name + '] WHERE CorporationId = ''52D3AEFE-8EBD-4669-8096-4596FE83BB36'''
FROM sys.columns c
    inner join sys.tables t
        ON t.object_id= c.object_id
    inner join sys.schemas s
        ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
where c.name = 'CorporationId'
```

and then either copy and paste the results into a new query window and execute the new query or iterate over the results with a cursor and execute each result with the `exec` statement.

Comment: You could also use this method with a cursor to execute the commands as well as easily modify this for a stored procedure. Upvote because I like it.

Comment: useful script, I am keeping this for later use in case my other examples do not work out!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c5ac2/2) that proves the below query

You can get the tables from this query:

```
SELECT Name, IsChecked = 0
INTO #Tables
FROM sys.Tables
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT * FROM sys.columns 
  WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(sys.Tables.Name) AND sys.columns.Name = 'blah'
)
```

Then, you can create a dynamic query and execute it for the tables that you found

```
WHILE(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Tables WHERE IsChecked = 0) > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @TableName = Name FROM #Tables WHERE IsChecked = 0
    SET     @DeleteQuery = 'DELETE FROM ' + @TableName  + ' WHERE CorporationID = ''' + @CorporationId + ''''
    EXECUTE sp_executeSQL @DeleteQuery;
    UPDATE #Tables SET IsChecked = 1 WHERE Name = @TableName 
END
```