# Combing two SQL queries

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have two SQL queries

First query will generate few ID's like 33,155,1661....

```
SELECT tal.ID 
FROM CUST_TICKETS tkts, TICKETS_ASSOC_LOGS tal  
WHERE tkts.TICKET_ID = tal.TICKET_ID 
  AND tkts.CUSTOMER_ID IN (66, 304)
```

and by comparing the above ID's I have to delete data from other tables, where table names like 'logs%'

Second query is

```
SELECT table_name, column_name 
FROM cols 
WHERE table_name LIKE 'LOGS_%' 
  AND column_name LIKE 'ID';
```

The above query will generate few tables like LOGS_1, LOGS_3 .....

The above tables contains ID column and has no dependencies with other tables

Finally I want to delete data from the tables(LOGS_*) generated by second query by comparing with ID's generated by first query

Thanks in advance

Comment: @VenkatKrishan ..you should look here for cursor and exec usage http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344054/run-a-delete-statement-certain-table-names-stored-in-a-table

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s Any Other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

you can just simply delete the data by combining queries like..

```
delete from logs where log_id in(SELECT tal.ID FROM CUST_TICKETS tkts , TICKETS_ASSOC_LOGS tal  where tkts.TICKET_ID=tal.TICKET_ID and tkts.CUSTOMER_ID IN (66,304) )
```

**logs is the table name generated by second query.**